# Getting attribute values from nodes and checking for empty nodes using LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

Using LINQ to XML, I am trying to get the attribute values: "name1 and name2" from the "media" node:

```
<server>
 <networkAdapters>
 </networkAdapters>    
 <media name1="test1" name2="test2">
   <groups>
      <group name="Group Name">
   </groups>
   <others>
   </others>
 </media>
</server>

The code should also check for null or non existent nodes at all, for instance:

<server>
 <networkAdapters>
 </networkAdapters>    
 <media>
   <groups>
   </groups>
   <others>
   </others>
 </media>
</server>

or

<server>
 <networkAdapters>
 </networkAdapters>
</server>
```

I am fairly new to LINQ to XML and I was trying the following:

```
string attribute1 = doc.Descendants("media").Select(s => s.Attribute("name1")).ToString();
string attribute2 = doc.Descendants("media").Select(s => s.Attribute("name2")).ToString();
```

I know is totally wrong but it's a beginning. Any help is welcomed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name1 = (string)(xDoc.Root.Element("media") ?? New XElement("media")).Attribute("name1");
```